# Error while trying to deploy smart contract

Tags: blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, ethers.js, hardhat

I had been trying to deploy a smart contract to localhost when I ran into this error. Can anyone help me?

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'format')
    at Function.from (C:\Users\bagak\Desktop\Dev\Web3.0\dessenger-v2\node_modules\ethers\src.ts\abi\interface.ts:1259:33)
```

I was trying to delpoy the smart contract but received an error instead. Tried googling up possible solutions. Couldn't find anything that would help

Comment: Provide your deployment script, please